# Placeholder for form_widget choices on Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

Using PHP on controller side, i can add a placeholder to my field using the createFormBuilder():

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($company)
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('cities', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'NexBaseBundle:City',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
                ))
                ->getForm();
```

I am looking to add a placeholder using Twig, for simple fields i can use attr like this :

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'My placeholder'} }) }}
```

I have tried with this but no luck:

```
{{ form_widget(form.cities, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Choose your city'} }) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't because the "select box" on html5 does not have an attribute "placeholder", your attribute "placeholder" in your formbuilder is an alternative of **empty_value**

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5791

Comment: i know, i say the "placeholder" doesnt existe in html5 for "select box", in symfony2 "placholder" is an lternative of "empty value" which is transformed into HTML to: <select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
    <option value="value">text</option>
</select>

Comment: Ok, But how can i customize it using Twig !?

Comment: Actually with twig, you can't do that :(

Answer (score 1):

On the createFormHandler its the [empty_data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-data) option. You can use the [placeholder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder) option but its possible that you get some trouble in older Browsers.

Normally i disable that HTML5 functions and do it with Javascript.

http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Here is a cool jQuery plugin to fix that problem in older Browsers.

Setting the value from your controller make not really sense. You can set a key in your form and translate them for example.

You can add the attribute only on text fields. Your second method on a Selext-Box is not working because there is not attribute **placeholder** on that element. So you can use the placeholder in your FormType but that is changed to an option field in background.

Comment: You pointed out some interesting cases in your response, still don't see how can i customize the default value on my select box. indeed, when i place it using the formbuilder it works, But like you said it doesn't make sense to place it on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how I am currently adding placeholders (My select list can be different then yours, but you can play around of this snippet):

```
{% form_theme cart_form _self %}

{% block choice_widget %}
    {% if form.vars.choices is defined %}
        {% for choices in form.vars.choices %}
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="{{ form.vars.full_name }}" class="form-control">
                        <option value="__none">--Choose</option>
                        {% for choice in choices %}
                            <option value="{{ choice.value }}">{{ choice.label }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```