# Appending an option to a select box inside twig template using Symfony 5

Tags: forms, symfony, drop-down-menu, twig

I am rendering a form inside a twig file. I just want to add a default/selected option to the select field and I need to do it inside the twig rather than `controller`, `entity`, or the `formType`.

Here is the code in my twig file:

```
{{ form_start(prdForm) }}
    <div class="form-group">
       {{ form_row(prdForm.productTitle, {'label': "Product Title", 'attr': {'placeholder': "Enter Product Name", 'class': "form-control"}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       {{ form_row(prdForm.productDescription, {'label': "Description", 'attr': {'placeholder': "Provide a short description for this product.", 'class': "form-control"}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose an item...</option>
        {{ form_widget(prdForm.category, {'label': "Select Category", 'attr': {'class': "form-control"} }) }}
   </div> 
{{ form_end(prdForm) }}
```

Comment: Why must you do it in the twig file instead of the controller? It smells like bad practices ;-)

Comment: same question, can you explain why you cannot use the `Entity`? which the easiest place to put your default value using the `__construct` method

Comment: @Frank B, This is going to be needed in one twig file across the project.

Comment: @PierrickRambaud, thank you for mentioning it, though I am still looking fro a solution to achieve that within the `twig` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use choice type inside your form. take look on this https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage 
cheers

Comment: $Badr, following the example given in the docs would override the database-driven content of the select filed with the selected option. How can I append a new option on top of all other options fetched from DB? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution to add a placeholder option into your select field within the twig file, not the best answer but at least it works:

```
{% do prdForm.category.setRendered %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{prdForm.children.category.vars.id}}" class="required">Category</label>
        <select name="{{ prdForm.children.category.vars.full_name }}" id="{{prdForm.children.category.vars.id}}" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose a category</option>
            {% for option in prdForm.children.category.vars.choices %}
                <option value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
```

Of course, thanks to another user for his answer here:
[Placeholder for form_widget choices on Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27657483/6546935)